# How to get the data from line number n to last line from a multi-line string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I am executing the following curl request in ruby:

```
cmd="curl --silent --insecure -i -X GET -u \"local\username:password\" \"https://example.com/Console/Changes\""
response = `cmd`
```

It is resulting in the following output:

[image]

From the above output it seems to be the response variable contains a multi-line string value. Just to confirm, I am trying to print the type of 'response' variable here:

`puts response.class`

Output here is:

> String

How to extract header info and the json body separately from the above response?

Comment: It's probably a lot easier to use a gem or the standard lib for HTTP requests. See https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/ - it's a converter from CURL to ruby code. There are also many gems for this such as [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb)

Comment: @ShanthaDodmane : If you run an external command using backquotes, the result will **always** be of type `String`, and hold the standard output of the command. If you want to access parts of this string, you have to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's better ways to do HTTP requests in Ruby, e.g. using the standard library's [`Net::HTTP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Having said that, I'll answer your question.

The HTTP standard [specifies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) that the header and the body are separated by an empty line containing just a CRLF (`\r\n`). Each line of the header also ends with a CRLF. Thus, we can simply split the response at the first occurrence of two CRLF, i.e. at the string `"\r\n\r\n"`.

Since this sequence might also appear in the body, we need to specify that we want our split to have at most 2 elements.

```rb
header, body = response.split("\r\n\r\n", 2)
```

Note though that with this the last header line will not end in `"\r\n"`, but that shouldn't be a problem. The technically more correct version would be to split at `"\r\n"` followed by a `"\r\n"`. That way we don't strip the trailing `"\r\n"` when splitting. This can be done with a regular expression using a look-behind:

```rb
header, body = response.split(/(?<=\r\n)\r\n/, 2)
```

---

The answer to your question in the title is a bit different though:

> How to get the data from line number n to last line from a multi-line string in ruby?

```rb
response.lines[n..].join
```

(Before Ruby 2.6 the range needs to be specified as `n..-1`.)